# While loop without blocking console output

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have been working on some multithreaded console applications recently and was wondering how to do this. I use this code to control the amount of threads created by the application:

```
foreach(string s in File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")){
    while (threads >= maxThreads) ;
    Thread t = new Thread(() => { 
        threads++;
        //thread code - make network request using 's'
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        threads--;
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    });
    t.start();
}
```

However, due to the while loop, the `Console.WriteLine` method in the created is blocked and does not show up until the next free thread is available.

Is there any way I can prevent this while loop from blocking the `Console.WriteLine` call?

EDIT - Reversed condition in while loop.

Comment: Are you sure that's what's happening? If the thread has already started, it won't be blocked by a busy-loop in the main thread.

Comment: Also, don't write to the console from multiple threads if you can avoid it. The console is not multi-thread friendly. Your threads will end up blocking each other waiting for the console.

Comment: I can't see any other problem that could be occurring - the thread created runs some time consuming functionality (such as web requests) which take up to a couple of seconds. I'm not very experienced with mutlithreaded apps so I guess I'm asking the same question...

Comment: @Blorgbeard could you suggest another way of doing it?

Comment: Well, no, because I have no idea what you're doing. Writing "TEST" to the console for every line of a file does not require multiple threads.

Comment: I am making several web requests for every line in a file. In the request, the line of the file will be used as a parameter. The operation is supposed to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @Blorgbeard sorry - I should have explained that in the question...

Comment: And why are you writing to the console?

Comment: @Blorgbeard for status updates.

Comment: Uh, don't call Thread.Abort either, no need for that. Just let the thread end normally.

Comment: use TPL Parallel.foreach

Comment: We still don't really know what the problem is though. The threads seem to be blocking - it's *probably* not because of the while loop.. you could try putting a `Thread.Sleep(1)` inside it though.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and replies @Blorgbeard and others. I will try semaphores and Thread.sleep tomorow

Comment: The code has a number of other weaknesses.  (1) The increments and decrements should use `Interlocked` functions to prevent from race conditions (2) If the code between increment and decrement throws, you have a problem, because the counter will not be properly decrernented.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments...

The line

```
while (threads >= maxThreads) ;
```

is not a good way to await a change in thread state, because it will cause the CPU to spin in the while statement.  Instead, use one of the mechanisms intended for thread synchronization, such as a [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's [an example](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore) of a SemaphoreSlim used for a very similar situation.

```
class TheClub      // No door lists!
{
  static SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim (3);    // Capacity of 3

  static void Main()
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) new Thread (Enter).Start (i);
  }

  static void Enter (object id)
  {
    Console.WriteLine (id + " wants to enter");
    _sem.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine (id + " is in!");           // Only three threads
    Thread.Sleep (1000 * (int) id);               // can be here at
    Console.WriteLine (id + " is leaving");       // a time.
    _sem.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this was simply a mistake in my question. I feel so stupid - I will edit the question!

Comment: @rodit Remove the semicolon.

Comment: Even after the edit, your `while` loop does not include the thread creation and Console.WriteLine because of the `;` after the while, and because there are no {} to include multiple statements in the while body.

Comment: @Eric I think you misunderstand the intent of the code - it looks like he means it to wait until threads <= maxThreads before creating new threads

Comment: The whole point of the loop is to prevent further execution on the main thread until one thread has completed operation to make space available.

Comment: Oh... well in that case you have a CPU-burning `while` statement.  Use a different construct to signal that the main thread can resume.

Comment: Yup. @rodit, your while loop condition was correct the first time.

Comment: @rodit: Updated my answer based on a correct understanding of your question.

Comment: @rodit: "*to prevent further execution on the main thread*" - very good idea. That's chapter 1 from "*How to write unresponsive programs*".

Answer (score 4):

Using the while loop and thread.abort (or thread.suspned) etc are CPU intensive and is not the right way for thread synchronization. Explore Manual and AutoResetEvents. They are very effective when it comes to thread synchronization and does not spike your CPU.

Comment: A semaphore is better suited.